# In Typescript, is it possible to make a property name of a Javascript Object accept multiple values?

Tags: javascript, object, typescript, key, javascript-objects

for example, if i create a new Object type:

```
interface NEWOBJECT {
    name: {};
}
```

would it be possible to make it so that name can be either name1 or name2, so that i can create NEWOBJECT's with *either* names as the property name for NEWOBJECT's?
like this:

```
var object1: NEWOBJECT = {name1: {}};
var object2: NEWOBJECT = {name2: {}};
```

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes

```
type NEWOBJECT = {
  [N in 'name1' | 'name2']?: {};
}
```

Unfortunately this still allows both properties to be either present or omitted, so I would actually follow a more precise approach using uniun types

```
interface NEWOBJECT1 {
  name1: {};
}

interface NEWOBJECT2 {
  name2: {};
}

type NEWOBJECT = NEWOBJECT1 | NEWOBJECT2;
```

Make sure you have the latest TypeScript.

Comment: I check your solution, but it throws error. See http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20NEWOBJECT%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BN%20in%20'name1'%20%7C%20'name2'%5D%20%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: @SurenSrapyan: Any content in that link is specific to you. Suggest you include what you tried and the results (error details) *in the question*.

Comment: @Richard Edited Thanks

Comment: My apologies I used the wrong syntax you need to use a type alias. I updated my answer

Comment: thanks for the response, i think that would work; is that the only way? i feel as if it's a rather roundabout way, since in my case i only care about the name, and duplicating the value as well feels like something that could be avoided, usually

Comment: hm.. also, when i try to access the property of a dynamic variable of a union type, the property must be in all of the types in the union, which kinda makes it pointless..

Answer (score 1):

If you set the type, it must use properties same names. But you can declare optional properties. And then you can declare your variable with one of them.

```
interface NEWOBJECT {
    name1?: {};
    name2?: {};
}
```

Comment: This is not the optimal solution because it doesn't require either. A union of two types would be better, although my approach is more concise

Comment: Actually turns out my Approach does not save you from the optionality problem so yours is as good, but I would still prefer a union

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have tried this, however, it allowed no properties or both properties to be accepted when creating the object

Comment: See here http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20NEWOBJECT%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name1%3F%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name2%3F%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj%3A%20NEWOBJECT%20%3D%20%7B%20name1%3A%20'TEST'%20%7D%3B
it allows to create with one property